# Does it satisfy Parallel trend assumption if coef before the shock is non-zero yet constant over time?

Tags: econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference, generalized-did

A shock happened in early 2003. I want to estimate how the shock changed the impact of X.

However, X existed all the time even before 2003. That's a difference from typical DID setting where X happens after 2003. I want to test how a shock in 2003 changes the impact of X that has always existed.

So, the estimation result from the usual test for parallel trend assumption (shown below) says the coefficient was negative already before the shock. I(YYYY) is the usual year dummy.

```
 Variable    Coef      p-value
I(2000)*X     -0.1      0.000
I(2001)*X     -0.1      0.000
I(2002)*X     -0.1      0.000
I(2003)*X     -0.2      0.000
I(2004)*X     -0.3      0.000
I(2005)*X     -0.4      0.000
```

So,

```
1. X still had some impact before the shock. It's non-zero.
2. Before the shock, the impact of X was pretty much constant over time.
3. X's negative impact becomes bigger after the shock.
```

Can I say this result satisfies the parallel trend assumption? Even if #2 and #3 are typical DID results that pass the parallel trend assumption, #1 invalidates the parallel trend assumption?

Or perhaps, am I just estimating a different thing than typical DID?

Usual parallel trend test wants to test is if X that occurred after 2003 had any impact before.

The parallel trend test I want to test is if X that always existed even before 2003 had smaller impact before compared to after the shock.